# WebAudio dB visualization not reflecting frequency bands as expected

Tags: javascript, angular, audio, data-visualization, web-audio-api

I've built a system-audio setup with WebAudio in an Angular component. It works well only the bands do not seem to reflect frequency accurately.

See here a test for high, mid, low tone test.

I've gotten pretty far with the native API, accessing a media stream etc. but it's not as helpful as a utility as I thought it would be...

Question:
How would we get the most accurate frequency decibel data?

**All** sounds seem to be focused in the first 3 bands.

Here is the method which visualizes the media stream (full code on [Github][2])

```
private repeater() {
    this._AFID = requestAnimationFrame(() => this.frameLooper());

    // how many values from analyser (the "buffer" size)
    this._fbc = this._analyser.frequencyBinCount;

    // frequency data is integers on a scale from 0 to 255
    this._data = new Uint8Array(this._analyser.frequencyBinCount);
    this._analyser.getByteFrequencyData(this._data);

    let bandsTemp = [];
    // calculate the height of each band element using frequency data
    for (var i = 0; i < this._fbc; i++) {
        bandsTemp.push({ height: this._data[i] });
    }
    this.bands = bandsTemp;
}
```

Boris Smus' [Web Audio API](https://webaudioapi.com/book/Web_Audio_API_Boris_Smus.pdf) book says:

> If, however, we want to perform a comprehensive analysis of the whole
> audio buffer, we should look to other methods...

Perhaps this method is as good as it gets. What is a better method for more functional frequency analysis?

Comment: A runnable example that doesn't require me to clone your repo would be really helpful. Also, the sample above is nice, but it's really hard to know what's happening.  It seems the tones are not running for very long, except, perhaps the low tone.

Comment: Hi @RaymondToy thanks for asking. I have one here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mediastream-device?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsys-sound%2Fsys-sound.component.ts but did not include it because I cannot get the Stackblitz environment to access my system devices... Does this help?

Comment: It would be better if it were runnable and smaller, but I can see that you set fftsize to 32.  That means the entire range of about 20 kHz is split into 32 equal-sized bins.  That might be a bit coarse.  A simple test using a oscillator to feed your analyzer would probably help you a lot in figuring out what's happening.  As it is, I can't help much because I don't know what the source is.  And as a demo, you don't even need any graphics.  Just dump out the fft values to the console once in a while.

Comment: Nice ideas, thanks. Yes I've done all that. In fact the fft is /2 so there are 16 bands but it doesnt matter. If I increase it we get slightly more coverage on this "low end" visual but the issue is still there. 

Seemingly 75% of sound is visualized within the first 1/8 of the frequency coverage.

Comment: Well, yes, the bands are linearly spaced instead of logarithmic so you have great low frequency resolution but not so good high frequency resolution. Nevertheless, a small runnable example illustrating the problem is best.

Comment: Hey @RaymondToy I worked on it since you recommended and I have the example functional only in FirefoxDevVersion (not Chrome) https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mediastream-device?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsys-sound%2Fsys-sound.component.ts

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the example in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mediastream-device?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsys-sound%2Fsys-sound.component.ts.  You're right that it doesn't work in chrome, but if I use the link to open it in a new window, everything is right.

So, I think you're computing the labels for the graph incorrectly.  I assuming they're supposed to represent the frequency of the band.  If not, then this answer is wrong.

You have `fqRange = sampleRate / bands`.  Let's assume that `sampleRate = 48000` (to keep the numbers simple), and `bands = 16`.  Then `fqRange = 3000`.  First I think you really want either `sampleRate/2/bands` or `sampleRate / fftSize`, which is the same thing.

So each of the frequency bins is 1500 Hz wide.  Your labels should be `1500*k`, for k = 0 to 15.  (Although there's more than one way to label these, this is the easiest.)  This will cover the range from 0 to 24000 Hz.

And when I play a 12 kHz tone, I see the peak is aroudn 1552 in your code.  But with the new labeling, this is the 8'th bin, so 1500*8 = 12000.  (Well, there are some differences.  My sampleRate is actually 44.1 kHz, so the numbers computed above will be different.)

Comment: Awesome @Raymond Toy and thank you. Relabelling does at least reinforce that the bands are the correct frequencies. I was initially hoping to see more separation of audio into frequency where this WebAudio vis still consistently has a lot of power in the lower fqs. I'll keep tinkering with that.

Comment: There are various ways to fix this, but the easiest way is to increase the fftSize, say 1024. That would give you a bin spacing of about 45 Hz, which might be enough resolution for what you want.